# Constructing Date-Periods Using "Since" in Api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a google-assistant application with api.ai that delivers data that has been aggregated over a date-period via a webhook.

It is common for people to ask for date periods using the word "since", for instance:
"*What is the data since last monday*" (tuesday - now)

or the even trickier:
"*What is the data since last year*". (ambiguous reference to date-period)

Can api.ai parse these date-periods, or is it necessary to identify if the intent request is of a special "relative" type and then construct the date-period manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to use something like the `@sys.date-period` pre-defined entity.

For example, if you create an Intent with a "User says" with parameters such as:
[image]

and a response:
[image]

and then enter in some queries like:[image: What is it since last monday?][image: What is it since last year?]

These might not be exactly what you need, so you may need to craft more of you own. If so, check out the `@sys.date` pre-defined entity, which may do some of the work for you, and the complete list at https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-entities#section-date-and-time

Comment: Thank you! I was surprised to see api.ai matching those phrases. 

The problem appears to have been in my training and utterances causing my @sys.date-period parameter to preferentially match phrases like "last year" over "since last year".